# How to create different viewModels for a common fragment?

Tags: android, viewmodel

In my Android app, there are three fragments with similar layout and functions, and only differs in a fetcher parameter. In short, it can be defined as

```kotlin
class MyFragment(private val fetcher: /* fetcher type */) : Fragment() {
    // Somme implementations
}

class MyFragmentViewModel(private val fetcher: /* fetcher type */) : ViewModel() {
    // ViewModel implementations
}
```

And to create these three fragments, I can just pass three different `fetcher`s to `MyFragment` and `MyFragment` needs to pass `fetcher` to its viewModel.

My question is, how to make the three fragments have its own viewModel? I get the fragment's viewModel by

```kotlin
val viewModel: MyFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
```

And if I do nothing, the three fragments may share the same viewModel, which does not match my requirement. I think this can be done by provide `factoryProducer` or `ownerProducer` to the `viewModels()` method, but I can't find many references about it, so I don't know how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out.

## Solution

First, I need to subclass `ViewModelProvider.Factory`:

```kotlin
class MyFragmentViewModelFactory(private val fetcher: /* fetcher type */) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return MyFragmentViewModel(this.fetcher) as T
    }
}
```

Then to use viewModel in my fragment:

```kotlin
val viewModel: MyFragmentViewModel by viewModels {
    NyFragmentViewModelFactory(fetcher)
}
```

## Something else

To use Navigation framework in this situation, just remove the `fetcher` argument in `MyFragment`, and use SafeArgs to pass an enum which resolves to different `fetcher`s.